# jQuery Tools, Tabs => Pane Resize & Load on Demand

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

First of all, I tried to post it in the jQuery Tools forum but I keep getting an error accessing their forum. "Authentication Required" Error.

Anyway, I am having problem with 2 things using jQuery Tools Tabs.

1. Is there a way to load Tabs only on demand ? For example I have a lot of images on Tab2 and I would not like the user to load those images until they click on tab2. This way, people will only load what they need.
2. On my css I have Pane Height as 100px. I would like to change the height according to each tabs. For example Tab1 should have height 100px, tab 2 should have height 500px.
   This is my code:

```
<div class="panes">

 <div>Tab1 Section: <br /> Sample</div> ( 100 px here)

 <div>Tab2 Section: <br /> Sample</div> (500 px here)
    </div>
```

css:

```
 .panes div { height: 100px; }
```

Comment: **Quote OP:** _"I tried to post it in the jQuery Tools forum but I keep getting an error accessing their forum"_ ~ This tells you everything you need to know about jQuery Tools... it's very close to being a dead project.

Comment: oh i see... sad to hear it, I didn't realize it..
would you happen to know another tab solution rather than jQuery tools tabs ?

Comment: I don't use tabs myself, but jQuery UI has this.